# Climbing the Totem Pole - Local Variables Become Parameters

Tags: c#, meta-programming, rubberduck

Along with the [Introduce Field](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/114050/34073) refactoring, I wrote an Introduce Parameter refactoring.

I actually wrote this refactoring first, but due to a bug in the parser/resolver, I was unable to fully test it until afterward.  Much of this codebase is shared, and I am going to write a helper class to support these, and other, refactorings, but other than this, this looks ready to go to me.  Please point out anything that you are concerned about.

```
public class IntroduceParameter : IRefactoring
{
    private readonly RubberduckParserState _parseResult;
    private readonly IList<Declaration> _declarations;
    private readonly IActiveCodePaneEditor _editor;
    private readonly IMessageBox _messageBox;

    private static readonly DeclarationType[] ValidDeclarationTypes =
    {
        DeclarationType.Function,
        DeclarationType.Procedure,
        DeclarationType.PropertyGet,
        DeclarationType.PropertyLet,
        DeclarationType.PropertySet
    };

    public IntroduceParameter(RubberduckParserState parseResult, IActiveCodePaneEditor editor, IMessageBox messageBox)
    {
        _parseResult = parseResult;
        _declarations = parseResult.AllDeclarations.ToList();
        _editor = editor;
        _messageBox = messageBox;
    }

    public void Refactor()
    {
        var selection = _editor.GetSelection();

        if (!selection.HasValue)
        {
            return;
        }

        Refactor(selection.Value);
    }

    public void Refactor(QualifiedSelection selection)
    {
        var target = FindSelection(selection);

        PromoteVariable(target);
    }

    public void Refactor(Declaration target)
    {
        PromoteVariable(target);
    }

    private void PromoteVariable(Declaration target)
    {
        if (target == null || target.DeclarationType != DeclarationType.Variable)
        {
            _messageBox.Show(RubberduckUI.PromoteVariable_InvalidSelection,
                RubberduckUI.IntroduceParameter_TitleText, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            return;
        }

        if (!PromptIfImplementsInterface(_declarations.FindSelection(target.QualifiedSelection,
                ValidDeclarationTypes), target))
        {
            return;
        }

        RemoveVariable(target);
        UpdateSignature(target);
    }

    private void UpdateSignature(Declaration targetVariable)
    {
        var functionDeclaration = _declarations.FindSelection(targetVariable.QualifiedSelection, ValidDeclarationTypes);

        var proc = (dynamic)functionDeclaration.Context;
        var paramList = (VBAParser.ArgListContext)proc.argList();
        var module = functionDeclaration.QualifiedName.QualifiedModuleName.Component.CodeModule;

        AddParameter(functionDeclaration, targetVariable, paramList, module);

        if (functionDeclaration.DeclarationType == DeclarationType.PropertyGet ||
            functionDeclaration.DeclarationType == DeclarationType.PropertyLet ||
            functionDeclaration.DeclarationType == DeclarationType.PropertySet)
        {
            UpdateProperties(functionDeclaration);
        }

        var interfaceDeclaration = GetInterfaceImplementation(functionDeclaration);
        if (interfaceDeclaration != null)
        {
            UpdateSignature(interfaceDeclaration, targetVariable);

            var interfaceImplementations = _declarations.FindInterfaceImplementationMembers()
                                        .Where(item => item.Project.Equals(interfaceDeclaration.Project) &&
                                               item.IdentifierName == interfaceDeclaration.ComponentName + "_" + interfaceDeclaration.IdentifierName);

            foreach (var interfaceImplementation in interfaceImplementations)
            {
                UpdateSignature(interfaceImplementation, targetVariable);
            }
        }
    }

    private void UpdateSignature(Declaration targetMethod, Declaration targetVariable)
    {
        var proc = (dynamic)targetMethod.Context;
        var paramList = (VBAParser.ArgListContext)proc.argList();
        var module = targetMethod.QualifiedName.QualifiedModuleName.Component.CodeModule;

        AddParameter(targetMethod, targetVariable, paramList, module);
    }

    private void AddParameter(Declaration targetMethod, Declaration targetVariable, VBAParser.ArgListContext paramList, CodeModule module)
    {
        var argList = paramList.arg();
        var lastParam = argList.LastOrDefault();

        var newContent = GetOldSignature(targetMethod);

        if (lastParam == null)
        {
            // Increase index by one because VBA is dumb enough to use 1-based indexing
            newContent = newContent.Insert(newContent.IndexOf('(') + 1, GetParameterDefinition(targetVariable));
        }
        else if (targetMethod.DeclarationType != DeclarationType.PropertyLet &&
                 targetMethod.DeclarationType != DeclarationType.PropertySet)
        {
            newContent = newContent.Replace(argList.Last().GetText(),
                argList.Last().GetText() + ", " + GetParameterDefinition(targetVariable));
        }
        else
        {
            newContent = newContent.Replace(argList.Last().GetText(),
                GetParameterDefinition(targetVariable) + ", " + argList.Last().GetText());
        }

        module.ReplaceLine(paramList.Start.Line, newContent);
    }

    private void UpdateProperties(Declaration target)
    {
        var propertyGet = _declarations.FirstOrDefault(d =>
                d.DeclarationType == DeclarationType.PropertyGet &&
                d.Scope == target.Scope &&
                d.IdentifierName == target.IdentifierName);

        var propertyLet = _declarations.FirstOrDefault(d =>
                d.DeclarationType == DeclarationType.PropertyLet &&
                d.Scope == target.Scope &&
                d.IdentifierName == target.IdentifierName);

        var propertySet = _declarations.FirstOrDefault(d =>
                d.DeclarationType == DeclarationType.PropertySet &&
                d.Scope == target.Scope &&
                d.IdentifierName == target.IdentifierName);

        if (target.DeclarationType != DeclarationType.PropertyGet && propertyGet != null)
        {
            UpdateSignature(propertyGet);
        }

        if (target.DeclarationType != DeclarationType.PropertyLet && propertyLet != null)
        {
            UpdateSignature(propertyLet);
        }

        if (target.DeclarationType != DeclarationType.PropertySet && propertySet != null)
        {
            UpdateSignature(propertySet);
        }
    }

    private void RemoveVariable(Declaration target)
    {
        Selection selection;
        var declarationText = target.Context.GetText();
        var multipleDeclarations = HasMultipleDeclarationsInStatement(target);

        var variableStmtContext = GetVariableStmtContext(target);

        if (!multipleDeclarations)
        {
            declarationText = variableStmtContext.GetText();
            selection = GetVariableStmtContextSelection(target);
        }
        else
        {
            selection = new Selection(target.Context.Start.Line, target.Context.Start.Column,
                target.Context.Stop.Line, target.Context.Stop.Column);
        }

        var oldLines = _editor.GetLines(selection);

        var newLines = oldLines.Replace(" _" + Environment.NewLine, string.Empty)
            .Remove(selection.StartColumn, declarationText.Length);

        if (multipleDeclarations)
        {
            selection = GetVariableStmtContextSelection(target);
            newLines = RemoveExtraComma(_editor.GetLines(selection).Replace(oldLines, newLines));
        }

        _editor.DeleteLines(selection);
        _editor.InsertLines(selection.StartLine, newLines);
    }

    private string GetOldSignature(Declaration target)
    {
        var rewriter = _parseResult.GetRewriter(target.QualifiedName.QualifiedModuleName.Component);

        var context = target.Context;
        var firstTokenIndex = context.Start.TokenIndex;
        var lastTokenIndex = -1; // will blow up if this code runs for any context other than below

        var subStmtContext = context as VBAParser.SubStmtContext;
        if (subStmtContext != null)
        {
            lastTokenIndex = subStmtContext.argList().RPAREN().Symbol.TokenIndex;
        }

        var functionStmtContext = context as VBAParser.FunctionStmtContext;
        if (functionStmtContext != null)
        {
            lastTokenIndex = functionStmtContext.asTypeClause() != null
                ? functionStmtContext.asTypeClause().Stop.TokenIndex
                : functionStmtContext.argList().RPAREN().Symbol.TokenIndex;
        }

        var propertyGetStmtContext = context as VBAParser.PropertyGetStmtContext;
        if (propertyGetStmtContext != null)
        {
            lastTokenIndex = propertyGetStmtContext.asTypeClause() != null
                ? propertyGetStmtContext.asTypeClause().Stop.TokenIndex
                : propertyGetStmtContext.argList().RPAREN().Symbol.TokenIndex;
        }

        var propertyLetStmtContext = context as VBAParser.PropertyLetStmtContext;
        if (propertyLetStmtContext != null)
        {
            lastTokenIndex = propertyLetStmtContext.argList().RPAREN().Symbol.TokenIndex;
        }

        var propertySetStmtContext = context as VBAParser.PropertySetStmtContext;
        if (propertySetStmtContext != null)
        {
            lastTokenIndex = propertySetStmtContext.argList().RPAREN().Symbol.TokenIndex;
        }

        var declareStmtContext = context as VBAParser.DeclareStmtContext;
        if (declareStmtContext != null)
        {
            lastTokenIndex = declareStmtContext.STRINGLITERAL().Last().Symbol.TokenIndex;
            if (declareStmtContext.argList() != null)
            {
                lastTokenIndex = declareStmtContext.argList().RPAREN().Symbol.TokenIndex;
            }
            if (declareStmtContext.asTypeClause() != null)
            {
                lastTokenIndex = declareStmtContext.asTypeClause().Stop.TokenIndex;
            }
        }

        var eventStmtContext = context as VBAParser.EventStmtContext;
        if (eventStmtContext != null)
        {
            lastTokenIndex = eventStmtContext.argList().RPAREN().Symbol.TokenIndex;
        }

        return rewriter.GetText(new Interval(firstTokenIndex, lastTokenIndex));
    }

    private Selection GetVariableStmtContextSelection(Declaration target)
    {
        var statement = GetVariableStmtContext(target);

        return new Selection(statement.Start.Line, statement.Start.Column,
                statement.Stop.Line, statement.Stop.Column);
    }

    private VBAParser.VariableStmtContext GetVariableStmtContext(Declaration target)
    {
        var statement = target.Context.Parent.Parent as VBAParser.VariableStmtContext;
        if (statement == null)
        {
            throw new MissingMemberException("Statement not found");
        }

        return statement;
    }

    private Declaration GetInterfaceImplementation(Declaration target)
    {
        var declaration = target;
        var interfaceImplementation = _declarations.FindInterfaceImplementationMembers().SingleOrDefault(m => m.Equals(declaration));

        if (interfaceImplementation == null) { return null; }

        var interfaceMember = _declarations.FindInterfaceMember(interfaceImplementation);
        return interfaceMember;
    }

    private bool PromptIfImplementsInterface(Declaration targetFunction, Declaration targetVariable)
    {
        var declaration = targetFunction;
        var interfaceImplementation = _declarations.FindInterfaceImplementationMembers().SingleOrDefault(m => m.Equals(declaration));

        if (interfaceImplementation == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        var interfaceMember = _declarations.FindInterfaceMember(interfaceImplementation);

        var message = string.Format(RubberduckUI.IntroduceParameter_TargetMethodIsInterfaceMemberImplementation,
            targetFunction.IdentifierName, interfaceMember.ComponentName, interfaceMember.IdentifierName,
            targetVariable.IdentifierName);
        return _messageBox.Show(message, RubberduckUI.IntroduceParameter_TitleText, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation) == DialogResult.Yes;
    }

    private string RemoveExtraComma(string str)
    {
        if (str.Count(c => c == ',') == 1)
        {
            return str.Remove(str.IndexOf(','), 1);
        }

        var significantCharacterAfterComma = false;

        for (var index = str.IndexOf("Dim", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 3; index < str.Length; index++)
        {
            if (!significantCharacterAfterComma && str[index] == ',')
            {
                return str.Remove(index, 1);
            }

            if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(str[index]) && str[index] != '_' && str[index] != ',')
            {
                significantCharacterAfterComma = true;
            }

            if (str[index] == ',')
            {
                significantCharacterAfterComma = false;
            }
        }

        return str.Remove(str.LastIndexOf(','), 1);
    }

    private bool HasMultipleDeclarationsInStatement(Declaration target)
    {
        var statement = target.Context.Parent as VBAParser.VariableListStmtContext;

        if (statement == null) { return false; }

        return statement.children.Count(i => i is VBAParser.VariableSubStmtContext) > 1;
    }

    private string GetParameterDefinition(Declaration target)
    {
        if (target == null) { return null; }

        return "ByVal " + target.IdentifierName + " As " + target.AsTypeName;
    }

    private Declaration FindSelection(QualifiedSelection selection)
    {
        var target = _declarations
            .Where(item => !item.IsBuiltIn)
            .FirstOrDefault(item => item.IsSelected(selection) && item.DeclarationType == DeclarationType.Variable
                                 || item.References.Any(r => r.IsSelected(selection) &&
                                    r.Declaration.DeclarationType == DeclarationType.Variable));

        if (target != null) { return target; }

        var targets = _declarations
            .Where(item => !item.IsBuiltIn
                           && item.ComponentName == selection.QualifiedName.ComponentName
                           && item.DeclarationType == DeclarationType.Variable);

        foreach (var declaration in targets)
        {
            var declarationSelection = new Selection(declaration.Context.Start.Line,
                                                declaration.Context.Start.Column,
                                                declaration.Context.Stop.Line,
                                                declaration.Context.Stop.Column + declaration.Context.Stop.Text.Length);

            if (declarationSelection.Contains(selection.Selection) ||
                !HasMultipleDeclarationsInStatement(declaration) && GetVariableStmtContextSelection(declaration).Contains(selection.Selection))
            {
                return declaration;
            }

            var reference =
                declaration.References.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Selection.Contains(selection.Selection));

            if (reference != null)
            {
                return reference.Declaration;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm still a fan of that message box interface. It'd be worthwhile to create a different project & nuget package for it IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not complain if you choose to keep the code as it is. It's readable and focused, except for the helper methods which you have already identified.

But we know that code is never finished, and there are always opportunities for improvements. So here are my nitpicks:

## In `Refactor(QualifiedSelection)`

You have a parameter selection, yet you pass that to `FindSelection()`. Do you have a selection or not? If you have one, why do you need to find it? If you need to find it, then it isn't really a selection, is it?

I don't want all these questions when I read code. My mind gets overloaded pretty quickly. And it shouldn't be necessary to look into all the members just to verify if they do what they say.

`FindSelection()` returns a `Declaration`. I think `FindDeclaration()` would be a better name.

## In `PromoteVariable()`

`RemoveVariable()` is called before `UpdateSignature()`, yet I have to scroll pretty far down to find `RemoveVariable()` while `UpdateSignature()` is the very first I see.

I would like to see `RemoveVariable()` listed first.

## `IMessageBox`

I like this interface, but the only variation, except from the text, are the buttons. Why not abstract the usage instead of copying the actual interface?

Like:

```
public interface IMessageBox
{
    void Inform(string message);
    bool Confirm(string question);
}
```

## In `RemoveExtraComma()`

It's hard to see if the logic is correct:

- Is it correct to simply remove a comma if there is only one?
- How many commas can there be? Is it possible that the method returns too early and remove the wrong comma?
- Will a reorder of the if statements change anything?
- The if conditions are complex. I would like to see variables or methods which explains what we are looking for, instead of having to parse them each time.

The statement:

```
statement.children.Count(i => i is VBAParser.VariableSubStmtContext) > 1
```

Can be written as:

```
statement.children.OfType<VBAParser.VariableSubStmtContext>().Count() > 1
```

## `GetParameterDefinition()`

Could be renamed to `CreateParameterDefinition()` or `DefineParameterDefinition()`. You are returning something that doesn't exist in the target code, so ,in my opinion, it shouldn't be a `Get...()`.

## `HasMultipleDeclarationsInStatement()`

Can be moved to `Declaration`.

## Wrap lists in types

The field

```
IList<Declaration> _declarations
```

Could be wrapped inside of a `DeclarationList` or `DeclarationCollection` and the related methods could be moved over there.

Comment: Thank you for the comments.  I recently renamed `FindSelection()` to `FindVariable()` because it is designed for `DeclarationType`s of `Variable`.  Also, it, `HasMultiple...`, and the two `GetVariableStmt...` methods were made into extension methods.  I have tested `RemoveExtraComma` in multiple use cases now, so I think it is correct.  Also, the order of the `if`s does count.  I should create an extensive comment for that method as it was a bit tricky to write.

Comment: Actually, your answer made me re-think what `RemoveExtraComma` did, and I found a serious bug.  I have completely rewritten it, and will likely give you the checkmark in a few days.

Comment: Also, `IMessageBox` is essentially a wrapper for `MessageBox` that we can mock in our tests.  It is used throughout the RD codebase with several different button/icon combinations, and will not be changed.